# Would it be safe to install the 11.10 Unity version in 11.04 after adding the GNOME 3 PPA?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

I was thinking of installing GNOME 3 in a regular Natty, but I would like to have the option to switch to Unity available. Since building Gnome Shell turned out being quite hard a task, I was considering installing Unity 4.x, the Oneiric version based on GNOME 3, via one of the avilable sources, such as Launchpad. Would this be possibile and safe? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: me too want to know if i can. since i have issues with 11.10 but i like the unity so can i have it on 11.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this ***might*** be possible, I would suggest that you rather just upgrade to 11.10. It would not be worth the trouble (and risk of breakage) to compile Unity 4.x on 11.04, while also trying to upgrade to GNOME3 (which will itself make your 11.04 system much closer to instability).

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm curious though, I'll set up a new partition to see if this is accomplishable. If anyone's interested I'll post another comment with the result.

Comment: It would be interesting to try, but it wouldn't be wise (even if it works) to put it out there in the wider community because new users who get curious are likely to try it and break something.